# Is NDC.org a legitimate way to track Chapter 13 cases?

Tags: united-states, bankruptcy

I was told by the secretary of the lawfirm that's handling my Chapter 13 case to go to ndc.org to find out details such as how many remaining payments I have.

I know a thing or two about technology, so I went to the site and checked it out.  After the fiasco of the Affordable Care Act's (aka Obamacare) website, I'm not surprised by what I find, but I don't know any other way to verify the site is legit or not.  Based on my other experiences with government websites, I can't say for certain this is a legit website.

Verifying sites like this is an important step to prevent identity theft, hence my concern.

Is this site legit?  I don't expect this SE to be familiar with all the technobabble below, but I would expect this SE to know if this domain is what it says it is because it's money related.

**Red Flags**

- There is no wikipedia entry for the site
- The site has a domain validated certificate, but I would expect extended validation
- The site mentioned 128 bit SSL security (which is now considered weak cipher strength) on their security page, but looking at the certificate in Firefox says 112 bits
- The certificate provides no ownership information to Firefox
- The only identifiable info in the certificate is that the NDC is in Lafayette California
- The site has a static web [page][1] that refers to a certificate by Verisign, yet the certificate is issued by Digicert (a competitor to Verisign)
- Website looks designed by a competent person/firm (scuttlebut and experience say that government websites are always painful)
- Searching DuckDuckGo for "whois "ndc.org"" only yeilds the site itself, no domain information
- Searching whois.net directly, I get "No Data Available"
- Most searches related to this site only return the site itself, no metadata; it seems a lot of stuff has been scrubbed off the net

**Seems Legit**

- Given link by attorney's secretary
- Link does not do any kind of crazy redirection, nor add crazy amounts of trash to the URL
- Searching for NDC on DuckDuckGo yields the site as the first result, but also a myriad of other National Data Centers
- Site is a combination of whiz-bang and government jargon, which seems plausible if this was a recent or ongoing government contract

  [1]: http s://www.ndc.org/online-security

Comment: Regarding "_yet the certificate is issued by Digicert (a competitor to Verisign)_", according to [DigiCert's Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DigiCert), "_In 2017 DigiCert acquired the TLS/SSL and Public Key Infrastructure businesses of Symantec, including the Certificate Authority brands Thawte, RapidSSL, **VeriSign** and GeoTrust._".

Comment: @TripeHound: and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symantec#Google_and_Symantec_clash_on_website_security_checks explains why. PS: the _connection_ from Firefox is 112 bit encryption, namely 3DES; this has nothing at all to do with the certificate, only the server. But https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.ndc.org says the server _prefers_ 3DES, which is bad, and RC4, which is awful, as well as not supporting any PFS.

Answer (score 1):

I can attest that the NDC.org site is 'legit'. The NDC is a non profit organization that is based in Lafayette, CA. I like some of the digital sleuthing done here! I'll work to get a wiki page going and see if we can get the SSL certificate beefed up too. If you have any issues or need further details about NDC or NDC.org, please email help@ndc.org